# I am trying to merge single digit ints into a single number

Tags: java, arraylist, int

I am getting an out of bounds error on the line where `x` is defined. What am I doing wrong?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.lang.Math;

public class poopy
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
       ArrayList<Integer> num = new ArrayList<Integer>();
       double x;

       for(int j=1; j<5; j++)
       {
          num.add(j);
       }

       for(int i: num)
       {
           x = num.get(i) * Math.pow(10,i);
           System.out.println(x);
       }


   }
}
```

This is going to be for a calculator and the int `ArrayList` will grow every time a number button is pushed.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to pass on the `foreach` loop and use an old-fashioned `for` loop:

```
   for(int i=0;i<num.size;i++)
   {
       x = num.get(i) * Math.pow(10,i);
       System.out.println(x);
   }
```

What happens is that you got the values of the array, but you need the indexes too. So, no foreach loop.

Comment: I've revised the code. I am still getting a problem with the value of x.

Say if 1 is pressed twice x gets the value of 112, and weirder still the value printed on the calculator screen is 12.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i: num)
```

i here is the value not the index.

Answer (score 0):

Your for (for-each) loop should be like this:

```
for(int i: num)
{
    x = i * Math.pow(10,i);
    System.out.println(x);
}
```

i instead of num.get(i)

if you want to access the items by index then you should not use the for-each loop, use the for loop as follows:

```
for(int i = 0; i < num.size(); i++)
{
    x = num.get(i) * Math.pow(10,i);
    System.out.println(x);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

With `num.get(i)` method you are accessing array by its index. Elements of your array are `[num[0]=1, num[1]=2, num[2]=3, num[3]=4]` .

loop `for(int i: num)` is accessing elements of `num` array and store them in a variable `i`.